# UIWindow creating NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints instead of NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uikit, autolayout

I created a simple iOS app that creates a UIViewController with a View in it. 
Here's the application delegate:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Here's the code in the UIViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  NSLog(@"breakpoint here");
}
```

I put a breakpoint on the "breakpoint here" line. Ran the app and typed this after it went to the debugger:

```
(lldb) po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]
$0 = 0x0a056d30 
*<UIWindow:0x8078de0>
|   *<UIView:0xa053fe0>
```

And here are the horizontal constraints on that UIView:

```
(lldb) po [0xa053fe0 constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis:0]
$1 = 0x0a05ba60 <__NSArrayM 0xa05ba60>(
<NSLayoutConstraint:0xa059560 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0xa053fe0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIWindow:0x8078de0 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0xa0595e0 UIView:0xa053fe0.right == UIWindow:0x8078de0.right>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x8571520 h=--- v=--- H:[UIWindow:0x8078de0(768)]>
)
```

So here's a simple question so I understand better. If autolayout is supposed to be the new thing to use instead of autoresizing masks, why is UIWindow forcing a NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint? Is there a different initializer I should be using to make UIWindow use regular constraints? Perhaps the initWithFrame on my UIWindow is to blame?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using storyboards or code to make the interface?

Comment: everything is in code

Answer (score 2):

By default, `UIWindow` and the top view of the controller are created with `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES` to help transitioning. From [cocoa-dev](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2012/Feb/msg00498.html):

> By default, Xcode will set the value of translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to YES for top level views, including those loaded for a view controller. The reason for this is also transitional: right now AppKit view subclasses usually expect subviews with translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints set to YES, and most applications are transitioning. Maybe some day in the future the default will be changed to NO.

You can disable using code, but you can't alter this behavior in an Apple provided way. You could use swizzling to accomplish it, but it's more civil to write the extra lines:

```
self.window.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; // application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; // viewWillAppear:
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that without enough constraints, views and UIWindow will fall back on autoresizing masks.

Constraints need to define size and origin. Without enough constraints Auto Layout won’t be able to define them.

[Auto Layout by Example](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=232) at WWDC 2012 should help.

(Are you having issues with UIWindow’s autoresizing masks? In my code I have translates on and only turn it off where I use Auto layout, I’m just beginning with Auto Layout though.)

Comment: problem is, with my code, i already disabled all autoresizing masks. (unless i missed something?). my question is basically, via code, how do i make it so no nsautoresize masks are created for any views or even nswindows?

Comment: My understanding is that you need more constraints. Enough to unambiguously define size (width and height) and position (x and y). Does this help?